# adding element to stack

Tags: java, stack

I create a method in stack call adding in this method I want to add element after the element is specific form use for example if the number in stack is "1 2 3 5" and I choose number 3 and enter number 4 the stack should be "1 2 3 4 5" this my trying

```
int a[] = new int[6];
int Top = -1;

public void push() {
    if (Top > 6) {
        System.out.println(" the Stack Ovelflow");
    } else {
        Top = Top + 1;
        String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the element stack");
        a[Top] = Integer.parseInt(m);
    }
}

public void adding() {
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the element u want to add after it");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
    String s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the element u want to add to stack");
    int d = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == x) {
            a[i + 1] = d;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your backing array `a` has enough space, so you can insert a new element.

```
int[] a= new int[]{1,2,3,5};  // this has only 4 elements, you can't add a 5th
```

So you could do:

```
public void adding(){
  // ask user for input.... and all that
  // you need an array with one more element than a. lets call it b

  int[] b = new int[a.length + 1];

  // now you need to search for x. (this is, if x is a number in your array and not an index..it wasn't clear to me)
  // so if x is a number in the array (and not the index) you need to get the index of that number:
  int index = 0;
  for (; index < a.length; index++) {  // your index variable will increment on each step
      if (a[index] == x) {
          break;            // and you break out of the loop once you found x
      }
  }

  // now you know the index of x
  // first make a copy of the partial array after x (in your example its just {5})
  int[] c = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, index, a.length);  // this will copy all elements of a from "index" to "length"

  // and here the loop that will actually insert the new number and move the rest:

   int cIndex=0;  // we need that counter later to loop through the new array c
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { // loop through every element of b
        if (i <= index) {   // if i is currently smaller than your wanted index (there where you will find x)
            b[i] = a[i];  // then just copy the contents of a
        } else if (i == index+1) {  // we just stepped over x
            b[i] = d;         // so you can add your new number here
        } else {
            b[i] = c[cIndex];   // and here you copy the rest into b (the partial array we called c earlier)
            cIndex++;  // we need that new index, to get always the next element
        }            
    }
```

And that's it.  looks complicated and is by far not the best or most efficient solution. But it works and I hope it helps you getting further!

Comment: It might just be me, but I'm not convinced that writing code using the wrong data structures for the job makes a good didactic example. Java has always had plenty of collections that would do a better job than raw arrays for this problem.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: true, arrays are the least practical data stucture here and inserting elements somewhere in the middle has no longer anything to do with stacks. And what I wrote lacks educational value, for sure. I was just trying to give a "simple" example on how to handle arrays in this case. Now its up to OP to optimize the program and switch to Lists or what ever is better suited for that kind of problem. But it's still good to start with arrays before jumping to lists without completely understanding what happens in the background.

Comment: Perhaps you could improve the answer to also show how to do it properly or why arrays aren't right for the job?